# How to populate a drop-down box with a list

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a list of roles such as Manager and User, that need to be shown as options of my drop-down box. Currently I can show them using the following code, but not sure how to have indexes with their names.

presently, options name and their indexes are the same.

```
  Index   Name

  Manager Manager

  User    User
```

**but should be**

```
  Index Name

  1     Manager

  2     User
```

my list

```
 public interface Options{
      public static final String[] POSITION = {"Manager", "User"}; 
      ....
```

my code to use the list as source of drop down list

```
  <s:select name="Position" label="Positions" list="@com.myproject.interfaces.Lists@POSITION"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `List<Object>` rather than a `String[]`, or even a `Map<Integer, String>`:

```
public static final Map<Integer, String> POSITIONS = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {
    {
        put(1, "User");
        put(2, "Manager");
    }
};
```

And the .jsp just:

```
 <s:select name="Position" label="Positions" list="@com.myproject.interfaces.Lists@POSITIONS" />
```

What you put in the `Key` of the `Entry` goes to the `ListKey` in your `s:select`, and what you put in the `Value` goes to the `listValue`.

You can also have two different collections and populate the `<s:select>` specifying which one goes to both `ListKey` and `ListValue` attributes.

Comment: I used your answer but it shows an error on put..... which says invalid method declaration;return type required. Please also note I am going to have this code in my interface.

Comment: Then you can use the second choice: have two different arrays: one `String[]` to put in the `ListValue` of the `select` and one `Integer[]` for `ListKey`. Obviously, you need to populate them in the right order.